# Grey Border around the whole site

Tags: squarespace

How do I add a light grey border to a squarespace site like: http://mrwolfmagazine.com/ - I'm hoping to not have to use this theme as all I want from this one is the grey border.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the theme you end up choosing.. but try adding this to CSS

```
#canvas {
  border: 3px solid #C0C0C0 !important;
}
```